# Difference B/W controls and get in form ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

When i uses this code to build the app in ionic 2 , the error shows like this **[key : string] AbstractControl**

Here is the HTML page

```
<ion-item>
   <ion-label primary floating>FIRST NAME </ion-label>
   <ion-input type="text" id="firstname" class="form-control" formControlName="firstname"></ion-input>
 </ion-item>

 <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.firstname.errors && myForm.controls.firstname.dirty ">
 <small class="up"><i> Min 3 chars </i></small>
 </p>
```

When i give *ionic serve* its building but When i *give ionic* build its shows error

Comment: can you paste the full error log?

Comment: Error Message " Property 'firstname' does not exist on type '{ [key : string]: AbstractControl; }'"

Comment: When Im using android build i got past comment as  error@PrerakTiwari

Comment: can you post your whole code...from the error it appears that you have not created a formcontrol named firstname?